# What will memory will override by overflow in the code

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory

i got the following code:

```
char *func(char * a)
{
char b[1000];
strcpy(b,a);
return b;
}
```

(I know that the code is bad, because I return address of array, that will delete when I exit the function.) My question is, what will be deleted/override, if I put in "a", an array of 2000 chars, and "b" is only 1000 chars array. I read this question somewhere, and they said that by this code I can know what will override.

Comment: The definition of "undefined behavior" means that the resulting behavior is undefined, within the realm of C++. The answer to this question would be the same as the answer to "what's in a middle of a black hole?"

Comment: The value of `b` will be null when it returns.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How do you know its C++, its tagged both C++ and C.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the reliable book, said that by this function I can know what will override. I also thought its weird, but I thought I missed something. maybe we all do? or its just bad question

Comment: Check this page, the example used to demonstrate the error is almost identical to your example code: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/562.html

Comment: You've read about "stack smashing", the details of which are completely platform-dependent.

Comment: @MortenJensen I understand, correct me if I wrong, that this overflow, will rewrite the value of the pointer. right?

Comment: @t0mm13b Value of `b` will be after return  ... well, value of `b` which now doesn't exist.

Comment: @asdasasda I don't know what you are getting at here. If the string in `a` is longer than `b` can accommodate, you'll likely see a segfault. The reason is, it is undefined behavior and you cannot reliably know what will happen when invoking it.

Comment: @asdasasda You one of those guys who like hacking things. Learn some assembly language(s) and a good debugger with memory visualizer. It may answer many of your questions. Formally speaking, this is UB, but on most platforms, writing post stack based buffer will overwrite what were previously on the stack: return addresses, variables, register saving zones, etc. Even if program survives this somehow, it is a security hole (e.g. attacker can overwrite return address to whatever he wants and to call arbitrary code). This is why a sized version, `strncpy` exists.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not familiar with the idea of stack. When the program control enters into a function a pointer to stack is given to the program control. And all local variables are allocated on this stack. When program returns from the function then the stack pointer is changed to it's original value. Therefore b is on stack and 1000 bytes are allocated for it. And when program returns from func then in fact nothing will be deleted or overwritten until some other function uses that area of stack. You can try accessing 'b' just after you come out from the function and it must work. But suppose after calling 'func' you call another function 'func1' which has some local variables then updating those variables will overwrite the content where b is pointing

Answer (score 0):

> what will be deleted/override, if I put in "a", an array of 2000 chars, and "b" is only 1000 chars array.

The behaviour is undefined. From the standard's perspective, nothing is guaranteed. Some memory could be overwritten, or it might not be. In practice, it's likely that some memory would be overwritten.

> correct me if I wrong, that this overflow, will rewrite the value of the pointer. right?

It could. It might not. The behaviour is undefined.

What will happen depends on the compiler, the version of the compiler, the cpu architecture, the compilation options, how the rest of the program is defined and possibly other factors.

In a typical implementation, the return value fits in a register and is a compile time constant so in practice it is unlikely to be stored on the stack in which case it would not be affected by the overflow. There are much more dangerous potential side-effects, such as the function returning in a completely different place than where it was called from.

Answer (score 0):

If the C-string in `a` that you pass is bigger than the space you allocated for `b` (1000 bytes) it will happily write past the end of `b` and down through whatever is on the stack below `b`. A C-string has no defined length. `strcpy(b,a)` will keep copying bytes into `b` until it finds a `\0` inside `a`. On your function `func`'s stack, the compiler will reserve 1000 bytes for `b` then save the return address to whatever called `func`. If `a` overwrites `b` you'll write over the return address and when `func` returns you'll jump to some random address with horrible results. Each compiler is free to put the return address from the function wherever it likes. Maybe it puts the return address at the top of its stack. But even in that scenario you'll be writing over stuff that you should not be writing over. If you're lucky you'll get an access violation.

To protect against this you can use `strncpy(b,a,sizeof(b)-1)` and put a `\0` at the end of `b`. Best to check `strlen(a)` and handle the error sanely if `strlen(a) > sizeof(b)-1`.

This is exactly the "buffer overrun" technique that hackers used to break Windows security restrictions. You call a Windows function that expects a C-string but does not check the length of the C-string that is passed in. The string that is passed in guesses the length of the input buffer and eventually it guesses correctly and overwrites the return address of the function to point into the string that was passed in. The remainder of the input string contains machine code instructions that then operate under the security permissions of the Windows function. It can then do whatever it wants.

Microsoft closed this security loophole long ago, but it remains as a good lesson to check the length of C-strings that you accept as input parameters.

Comment: If you check the length of C-strings that you accept as input parameters you don't need to check for overruns when you copy them. That `strncpy` dance is almost always ill-advised (because most people don't do it right) and, if you write **correct** code (as you've suggested) you don't need it.